# Step by step instructions to abandon a Debian package and no longer be its maintainer

Tags: debian, packaging, deb

I am marked as the Debian maintainer of a package. I no longer wish to be the maintainer of this project. I thought I had gone through the process of abandoning the package, but it looks like I haven't. It has been years since I did any Debian packaging, and so I need help to follow the [instructions posted in the Debian manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/pkgs.en.html#orphaning):

> 5.9.4. Orphaning a package
>
> If you can no longer maintain a package, you need to inform others, and see that the package is marked as orphaned. You should set the package maintainer to `Debian QA Group <packages@qa.debian.org>` and submit a bug report against the pseudo package wnpp. The bug report should be titled `O: package -- short description` indicating that the package is now orphaned. The severity of the bug should be set to `normal;` if the package has a priority of standard or higher, it should be set to important. If you feel it's necessary, send a copy to `debian-devel@lists.debian.org` by putting the address in the X-Debbugs-CC: header of the message (no, don't use CC:, because that way the message's subject won't indicate the bug number).
>
> If you just intend to give the package away, but you can keep maintainership for the moment, then you should instead submit a bug against wnpp and title it `RFA: package -- short description`. `RFA` stands for `Request For Adoption`.
>
> More information is on [the WNPP web pages](https://www.debian.org/devel/wnpp/).

I'm struggling to follow even the first step. How do I set the package maintainer to another email address, for instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table of contents:

1. Report a bug to Debian `wnpp`
2. Update the `Maintainer` field on the package

## Part one: Reporting a bug to Debian `wnpp`

You can report a bug against the package, saying that the package is orphaned now, and asking for adoption. Hopefully, one of the Debian maintainers will see the bug report and will do the work of changing the `Maintainer` field on the Debian package metadata to `Debian QA Group <packages@qa.debian.org>` for you, if not, see the second part of this answer.

To report a bug to Debian, the documentation recommends that you use the tool `reportbug`. However, `reportbug` doesn't work by default unless you have configured a Mail Transport Agent, like exim or sendmail. Instead, send a simple plain text email.

Open your email client, and compose a new message:

- The recipient should be submit@bugs.debian.org
- The sender should be the same email address as the one that is the current maintainer of the package, I presume.
- The subject should be in this format: `O: PACKAGENAME -- short description of the package` . The `O:` here stands for orphaning. For example, the subject could be `O: firefox -- a browser`.
- It is important that you enable plain text mode in your email client.
- Make the contents of the email look like this:

  ```
  Package: wnpp
  Severity: normal

  Dear Debian maintainers,

  I no longer wish to be marked as the maintainer of this Debian
  package, PACKAGENAME. Could someone mark this package as orphaned? Thank you.
  ```

The package `wnpp` is a virtual package used to track bug reports about orphaned Debian packages.

You should receive an email a few minutes later acknowledging the receipt of the bug report.

## Part two: Updating the `Maintainer` field on the package (optional but recommended):

Once that bug report is accepted, the package is considered orphaned. However, to unsubscribe from any bug report emails from the Debian package, the `Maintainer` field of the Debian package needs to be changed. A Debian developer may do it for after you submitted the bug report, but you can do it yourself, too.

You will need to be using a computer on Debian or a Debian derived distribution to do this.

1. Make sure that the source repositories are enabled. ([See this](https://askubuntu.com/q/158871/2355))
2. If you are not using Debian, you probably want to enable the Debian repositories by modifying `/etc/apt/sources.list` to include this line. It's important to undo this afterwards:

   ```
   deb-src [trusted=yes] http://http.us.debian.org/debian unstable main non-free contrib
   ```
3. Run `sudo apt update`
4. Run `apt-get source PACKAGENAME`, replacing `PACKAGENAME` with the package that you want to mark as orphaned. This will download some tarballs and signatures to the current directory, and some files will be extracted to a subdirectory. For example:

   ```
   $ apt-get source PACKAGENAME
   $ ls
   PACKAGENAME-0.2/
   PACKAGENAME_0.2-5.1ubuntu1.debian.tar.xz
   PACKAGENAME_0.2-5.1ubuntu1.dsc
   PACKAGENAME_0.2.orig.tar.gz
   ```
5. Make sure that this version is the latest one in the Debian unstable repository.
6. Change directory to the subdirectory.
7. Modify `debian/control` to change this line so that the new maintainer is Debian QA Group:

   ```
   Maintainer: Debian QA Group <packages@qa.debian.org>
   ```
8. Add a new entry in the changelog by running `dch -i`: the new version number should increase in the number after the dash (for example, from 0.2-5 to 0.2-6). The changelog should look like this at the top:

   ```
   PACKAGENAME (0.2-6) unstable; urgency=medium

     * Set Debian QA Group as maintainer.

    -- Firstname Lastname <email@example.com>  Sun, 14 Jul 2019 22:26:08 -0300
   ```
9. Still in the subdirectory, run the following command ([see docs](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html)):

   ```
   dpkg-buildpackage
   ```

This will create more files in the parent directory, including `PACKAGENAME_0.2-6_amd64.changes`. It will also sign them using your GPG secret keys. If you have lost your secret keys, then you may get stuck at this step.

10. Now, upload your changes to the Debian servers ([see docs](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/upload.en.html)):

    ```
    dupload PACKAGENAME_0.2-6_amd64.changes
    ```
11. If you had added this line in step 2 to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, now is the time to undo that addition by deleting this line:

    ```
    deb-src [trusted=yes] http://http.us.debian.org/debian unstable main non-free contrib
    ```